# What's causing this ERROR 2000 (HY000): Unknown MySQL error

Tags: mysql, errors

I have a MySQL server with version 5.6.12-log (it's running on OpenSUSE). I can connect to it from another server (CentOS 6) using:

```
mysql -h **** -u **** --port **** -p
```

It prompts me for my password and connects just fine. The client version is "Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper."

However, from another server (running CentOS 7), using the same command, I get the following error after entering my password:

```
ERROR 2000 (HY000): Unknown MySQL error
```

This error is useless. There is *nothing* in the client machine logs that indicate the cause of the failure. However, I *do* know that the MySQL server is at least receiving the connect request because it logs a warning about the Reverse DNS lookup not matching. It's just a warning—not the cause of this problem—but it proves that firewalls and/or network configurations aren't blocking the connection. There is nothing else in the MySQL server log (or error log) that indicates the cause of the failure. This client version is "Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper."

Help??? I'm lost here. In 10+ years of MySQL admining, I've never seen this error before. I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: This is a client error. Is it possible you use some other version (not 5.6.23) to check whether the error persists or not?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use another version of the client from that machine. I can tell you that the same client can connect to the _local_ server without error. It just can't connect to the remote server. Also, the 5.6.12 client on a different machine can connect to the remote server. :-/ Is there really _no way_ to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Anything in mysqld.err?  Is skip_name_resolve turned on?  Is there a firewall?  Selinux?  Will it work if you use the IP-address instead of the hostname?

Comment: 1. On the client machine, no log is generated. On the server machine, `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log` is empty and `/var/log/mysql/mysqld-error.log` has a warning about the client's reverse DNS not matching. 2. `skip_name_resolve` is turned off on the server. 3. There is a firewall and it is not the problem (the connection is reaching the server as per the warning in the log file). 4. SELinux is enabled on the server machine, the client machine that can connect, and the client machine that can't connect. 5. I'm already using the IP address and not the hostname, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out, and it isn't pretty. I guess I'll have to file a bug with MySQL.

- The server is compiled with OpenSSL.
- The working client is compiled with OpenSSL.
- The client that can't connect is compiled with yaSSL.

The user I was trying to connect with used the `sha256_password` authentication plugin. When I dropped and re-created the user with `mysql_native_password` instead, the problem went away and I can connect from all clients. It appears that the `sha256_password` plugin doesn't work if the server and client are compiled against different SSL providers. (It might not even work with yaSSL at all.)

Comment: Bug reported: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75867

Answer (score -1):

I use this command "service mysqld stop" and "service mysqld start" to restart my mysql service, mysql work well.

Comment: Hey there @chengwengao! How does this answer help answer the question? Maybe if you provided more detail it would help us understand. Thanks!